# R При создании новой переменной, все данные удаляются и остается только новая переменная

Tags: r

Нужно создать переменную подсчитывающее количество наблюдений согласно условию фильтра.
При запуске кода все данные удаляются и сохраняется только переменная yes_4. Что нужно изменить в коде?

```
dataset <- dataset %>%
  filter(number == 4 & condition == 'Yes') %>%
  summarize(yes_4 = n())
```

Comment: либо уберите присвоение совсем, либо сохраняйте результат под другим именем: `другое.имя <- dataset %>% ...`

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, у вас теряется часть наблюдений (строк) при фильтрации. Вы должны об этом помнить. Во-вторых, наверное, подойдет вариант с использованием функции `mutate()` из `dplyr`. Она добавит новый столбец к существующим.

```
df %>% filter(...) %>% mutate(...)
```